# Проблемы при парсинге сайта

Tags: парсер

Есть следующий код:

```
import requests
import socks
import socket
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from fake_useragent import UserAgent


for i in range(7):
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument("window-size=1280,720")
    ua = UserAgent()
    random_user_agent = ua.random

    socks.setdefaultproxy(proxy_type=socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, addr="localhost", port=9050) # использую tor для proxy
    socket.socket = socks.socksocket
    headers_data = {'User-Agent': str(random_user_agent)}
    r = requests.get("https://synapsenet.ru/search/tenderi-po-regionam", headers=headers_data)
    time.sleep(2)
```

После 3-4 запроса я получаю следующую ошибку:

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "categories_list.py", line 51, in <module>
    r = requests.get("https://synapsenet.ru/search/tenderi-po-regionam", headers=headers_data)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 498, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response',))
```

Уже долгое время не могу понять в чём ошибка и как её исправить. Очень нужна помощь.

Comment: А зачем вы одну и ту же страницу несколько раз запрашиваете? Да еще и с разными UserAgent и прокси

Comment: это как пример, а так я парсю весь сайт. Так что сделать с этой ошибкой?

Comment: не менять не пробовал?